# Autorelease on sheet completionHandler flags Xcode analyzer as over-released

Tags: xcode, cocoa, analyzer

All of this is non-ARC.

In my DocumentWindowController I call:

```
-(IBAction)showConfigSheet:(id)sender
{
    [[ConfigSheetController alloc] initWithDocument:[self document]];
}
```

Then in my ConfigSheetController class I have:

```
-(id)initWithDocument:(Document *)inDocument
{
    if (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:kConfigSheetNibName])
    {
        [self setDocument:inDocument];
        [[self window] orderOut:self];

        //  run the sheet       
        [[[self document] windowForSheet] beginSheet:[self window] completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode)
        {
            if (returnCode == NSModalResponseOK)
            {
                ... do stuff ...
            }

            else if (returnCode == NSModalResponseCancel)
            {
                ... do different stuff ...
            }

            //  we need to rebuild from the nib each time so release ourselves
            //  because we were alloc'd in the DocumentWindowController and
            //  this will release us after OK or Cancel is clicked

            [self autorelease];  
        }];
    }

    return (self);
}
```

For the [self autorelease], the Xcode analyzer is saying "Object autoreleased too many times". Why? The sheet happens within the block and once it is finished it releases the sheet as it returns.

This code works fine with no crash or errors in the console.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Xcode 8.0 (8A218a). You'll need to provide more details for people to be able to help you. You can also try a doing a `Clean Build Folder...` first.

Comment: I think it is because my initWithDocument: returns an autoreleased object (well actually with the completion handler it doesn't return anything at all but disposes of itself. Xcode 7.3.1 on 10.11.6.

Comment: `init…` methods are not supposed to return an autoreleased object. `init…` methods also shouldn't display sheets.